# Need to calculate Elapsed time between 2 Date time fields excluding weekends

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

I have the formula which calculates the number of hours elapsed between 2 DateTime fields excluding the weekends. Using this formula field in another calculation is giving Compile error.
Is there another efficient way of finding the elapsed time in Formula fields?

> Formula(s) that reference this field are no longer valid: Compiled formula is too big to execute (17,321 characters). Maximum size is 15,000 characters (Related field: Formula)

```
ROUND(
    24 * 
    (
        ( 
            5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(Temp_Close_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8)) / 7) 
            + MIN(
                5, 
                MOD(DATEVALUE(Temp_Close_Date__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) 
                + MIN(
                    1, 
                    24 * (MOD(Temp_Close_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 16:00:00'), 1) ) 
                )
            )
        ) 
        - ( 
            5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE(Last_Transfer_Date_Time__c) - DATE(1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) 
            + MIN(
                5,
                MOD(DATEVALUE(Last_Transfer_Date_Time__c) - DATE(1996, 1, 1), 7) 
                + MIN( 
                    1, 
                    24 * (MOD(Last_Transfer_Date_Time__c - DATETIMEVALUE('1900-01-08 16:00:00'), 1))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    0
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything beyond the most simple of Date/time calculations are generally best done using Apex instead of formulas.

That said, it does look like there are improvements that you can make here.

Swapping out your custom fields for the standard `CreatedDate` and `LastModifiedDate` (just so I have a point of reference) shows me that this formula has a compiled size of 1,261 characters.

Keep in mind that every time you reference a formula field inside of another formula field, you're adding the compiled size of the referenced formula field to your new formula. If `Temp_Close_Date__c` and/or `Last_Transfer_Date_Time__c` are formula fields, you'll want to minimize the number of times each are referenced. Failing that, taking time to reduce the compiled size of the referenced formulas is going to be the most effective way to reduce the compiled size of a formula referencing other formula fields.

In a nutshell, this formula:

- Finds the number of weeks between [Date] and [A known Monday] and multiplies by 5 (5 working days a week)
- Adds the remaining number of working days in the current week for [Date]

  - i.e. if [Date] is a Saturday or Sunday, we just add 5 days
  - but if it's Monday- Friday, we add the 0-indexed day of week (0 = Monday) and up to 1 additional day (a partial day if the time part of [Datetime] is not past 5pm)
- Does the same calculation for [Date 2] and subtracts it from the first part of the calculation

Put another way, this formula aims to:

- Find the number of full weeks between 2 dates, and multiplies that by 5 (to get working days)
- For the final, partial week between them, figure out how many working days there are
- Some adjustment to count time after 5pm as 1 day

Finding the number of full weeks between two dates can be simplified from
`5 * FLOOR([Date1 - Date2] / 7) - 5 * FLOOR([Date3 - Date2] / 7)` to
`5 * FLOOR([Date1 - Date3] / 7)`

That change brings the compiled size down to 863 characters for me

Finding the day of week can be more efficiently done using
`WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE([Datetime]))`
(which returns a number 1 - 7 with 1 being Sunday, subtracting 2 and mod 7 gets us 0-6 with 0 = Monday)

That change brings the compiled size down to 811 characters for me

The fine time adjustment can be done more efficiently using
`TIMEVALUE([Datetime]) - TIMEVALUE('16:00:00)`

Bringing me down to 807 characters.

So the moderately optimized formula ends up looking like

```java
ROUND(
    24 * 
    (
        /* Full weeks between dates */
        5 * FLOOR((DATEVALUE([Date1]) - DATEVALUE([Date2])) / 7) 
        +
        /* Partial week of the more current date */
        MIN(
            5, 
            MOD(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE([Date1])) - 2, 7) 
            /* With a fine adjustment for a partial work day */
            + MIN(
                1, 
                24 * (TIMEVALUE([Date1]) - TIMEVALUE('16:00:00'))
            )
        )
        - 
        /* Partial week of the more distant past date */
        MIN(
            5,
            MOD(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE([Date2])) - 2, 7) 
            /* With a fine adjustment for a partial work day */
            + MIN( 
                1, 
                24 * (TIMEVALUE([Date2])) - TIMEVALUE('16:00:00'))
            )
        )
    ),
    0
)
```

There may or may not be an improvement that can be made in figuring out the partial week adjustment. I imagine that it'd make use of `CASE()` (possibly nesting `CASE()` inside of `CASE()`).

The compiled size of the two `MIN(5, MOD(WEEKDAY([Date]) -2, 7)` bits is 197 characters, and using `CASE()` will eat way at some (or all) of that.

Comment: After a bit more work, trying to reduce the partial week component using `CASE()` actually increased the compiled size. There are still 3 references to each Datetime field in the formula, and I don't see any way to get rid of those. So if your Datetime field(s) are what's causing your existing formula to have a large compiled size, then these changes will have a minimal impact. In that case, optimizing the referenced formulas is the way to go (or just do it in Apex).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. The Time value difference isn't working I guess, am still trying to fix! But you gave some new ideas to try, thank you!

Comment: Yes, trying to convince Business so we could go for Bach flow and that way, we can eliminate Holidays as well!